# Is there a way in plantuml to force an element to be a tipe from an specific diagram after using "allow_mixing"?

Tags: plantuml

I've been trying to make a diagram with both classes stereotypes and common classes, using "allow_mixing" I can put in my diagram elements "boundary" and "control" of a deployment diagram and elements "class" of a class diagram without problem.

The issue is when I try adding an "entity" element it automatically declares it as an "entity" element of a class diagram as you can see here

**"allow_mixing" diagram**

[image: "allow_mixing" diagram]

but I want it to be an "entity" element of a deployment diagram. Is there a way to make it so?

This is my plantuml file

```
@startuml Design-Analysis-TraceDiagram
allow_mixing

boundary AdminExamView 
boundary NewExamView 
boundary ExamPublishedView
control CreateExamController
entity Exam
entity Questions
entity Answers

class AdminExamViewDes as "AdminExamView" <<JFrame>>
class NewExamViewDes as "NewExamView" <<JFrame>>
class ExamPublishedViewDes as "ExamPublishedView" <<JFrame>>
class CreateExamControllerDes as "CreateExamController"
class ExamDes as "Exam"
class QuestionsDes as "Questions"
class AnswersDes as "Answers"

AdminExamView <.. AdminExamViewDes
NewExamView <.. NewExamViewDes
ExamPublishedView <.. ExamPublishedViewDes
CreateExamController <.. CreateExamControllerDes
Exam <.. ExamDes
Questions <.. QuestionsDes
Answers <.. AnswersDes

@enduml
```